# Ĉu diferenco ekzistas inter firmo kaj firmao?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

Ĉu estas okazo, en kiu unu estas pli bona uzi ol la alia aŭ ĉu ĝi estas nur via elekto?  Is there occasion when one is better to use than the other or is it just your choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **noun** *firmo* in the sense of an enterprise is listed in *[Universala vortaro](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/universala_vortaro.html)* and thus is *Fundamenta*. There is also a fundamental **adjective** *[firma](https://vortaro.net/#firma_kd)*, firm, stable, fast. The origin of these words is in Latin, *firmus*, firm, stable → *firmare*, to make firm, to confirm by signature. By this logic a firm, company is something that is involved in transactions which you confirm by your signature.

In order to avoid confusion, whether *firmo* is a simple derivation from *firma* or has some other meaning, one has invented the word *firmao* which is strickly speaking a neologism, but has replaced *firmo* for all practical purposes.